# Camunda send list as process variable when start process

Tags: java, delegates, camunda

I have some process in my Springboot application and wanna start it via rest.

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/process-definition/Kvorum:2:c10196c1-1935-11eb-b60d-7a7bf841afbd/start
```

with body:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "list": {
            "value": "[\"1\",\"2\"]",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "businessKey": "myBusinessKey",
    "withVariablesInReturn": true
}
```

What do I need to write here:

```
"list": {
    "value": "[\"1\",\"2\"]",
    "type": "Object"
}
```

to receive List instead of String and use it in JavaDelegate with code like:

```
List<String> list = (List) execution.getVariable("list");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    "list": {
        "value": "[\"1\",\"2\"]",
        "type": "Object",
        "valueInfo" : {"objectTypeName": "java.util.ArrayList", "serializationDataFormat":"application/json"}
    }
```

Comment: Can you guide how we can do same thing for Map data type, i am able to get the Map working with Map within Map.